# GET Data from PHP

Tags: c#, php, http

I have a PHP login script. I should check login credentials which user entered on C# Metro application. My php script returns json data when succesful. So how can I make a connection between c#-php?

I know something about HttpWebRequest. I think I should use GET method to check login credentials. I tried download data from this link :

```
www.example.com/myscript.php?username=xxxx&password=12345
```

But it says error. And I can't any data when I tried it on browser.

Comment: Browser also doesn't work, so the problem is in your server and not in C#. Solve that problem first.

Comment: I hope this is over https. I would probably POST credentials and then GET the session.

Comment: show what you've tried ?

Comment: Post the what you've got on the PHP side. Also, bad idea to send credentials in a URL.

Comment: This app works on Android. So I think that it is not about server.

Comment: C# Metro application on Android?

Comment: we have no special powers to download all your code and understand your environments and requirements. we are going by what your saying.

Comment: Do **NOT** embed passwords in a URL. remember that query strings are logged in the server access logs, and now anyone with log access can read EVERYONE's password.

Comment: Sorry really. URL was fail. I was using wrong URL. Really sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you share your script and the errors you are getting? If you access the url with the browser and get an error, the metro app will of course also get an error.

Also, please make sure you are using https.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You don't have right to comment yet, when you do use the comment for this type of communication.

Comment: Ah ok, is there another preferred way to ask for more information without the ability to comment?

Comment: You need 50 reputation. you have 11 now when you get 50 you will see a comment link popup under the questions. I will bump you with another 10 so u need only 30 more :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try to answer simple questions to build up the reputation :)